# List all items from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm a beginner in react/web development and tried my first project. For the beginning I only want to list all pokemons from JS object in `<li>`.
I can't figure out what's wrong.
there's no error.

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

var Pokedex = require("pokedex-promise-v2");
var P = new Pokedex();

class PokemonsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pokemonList: [] };
    this.retrievePokemonList = this.retrievePokemonList.bind(this);
  }

  retrievePokemonList() {
    P.getPokemonsList()
    .then(function (response) {
      const listItems = response.results.map((d) => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>);
      this.setState({
        pokemonList: listItems
      })
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    //const listItems = response.results.map((d) => <li key={d.name}>{d.name}</li>);

    return (
      <div onLoad={this.retrievePokemonList}>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <div>{this.state.pokemonList}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <PokemonsList></PokemonsList>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In web console (F12) is this: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

Where's my error? How can I display all those pokemons. Thanks in advance

Comment: could you `console.log(response.results)`

Comment: lol for `catch` and Pokemon in the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the your code corrected:

```
import React from 'react';
import PokedexLib from 'pokedex-promise-v2';

class PokemonsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { pokemonList: [] };
    this.Pokedex = new PokedexLib();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.Pokedex.getPokemonsList()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          pokemonList: response.results,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Pokemon List</h1>
        <div>
          {this.state.pokemonList.map(pokemon => (
            <li key={pokemon.name}>{pokemon.name}</li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <PokemonsList></PokemonsList>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Please look 2 things, all the apis call is better you will do in the componentDidMount method, and the other thing is you can render the list inside the method render with the map method.. regards